# Qt's absoluteFilePath() method returns wrong path

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to print file's path pointed in treeView with following functions:
1) Setting root index for treeView:
`self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.model.setRootPath("/some/unix/catalog"))`
2) Setting connection between clicked file and function which prints name:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.print_path)`
3) Printing inside print_path function which takes (QModelIndex) index as an argument

`print QtCore.QFileInfo(index.data(0).toString()).absoluteFilePath()`
My problem is that I get:

`/path/to/source/files/of/the/project/nameofthefile.extension`
instead of:

`/path/to/pointed/file/nameofthefile.extension`
Even if pointed files are in subdirectories these functions return only name of file with extension concatenated to source files path.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
QtCore.QFileInfo(index.data(0).toString())
```

you are creating a new FileInfo instance with just the local path. The fileinfo has no possibility of knowing which folder this filename is in, so it uses the default folder. Think of it as

```
QtCore.QFileInfo("readme.txt")
```

How could the fileInfo know that you mean readme.txt to be in /my/nice/files/ folder?

You should get the fileInfo from

```
QFileSystemModel::fileInfo
```

So in your case:

```
self.model.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
```